# Real Ajax Uploader Error: Cannot write on file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-permissions, ajaxuploader

I'm building a site that requires the ability to upload large .wav files. I figured the best way to upload these files was via a jQuery plugin that could chunk the data to the server. I chose [Real Ajax Uploader](http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/index.php) to do this.

I put the following together and it works great for smaller files:

```
$('.demo').ajaxupload({
    url : '/upload.php',
    remotePath: '/remote/path/',
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFileSize: '250M',
 });
```

The problem occurs when I have a larger file that involves "chunking". For some reason the script keeps giving me this error:

```
Cannot write on file.
```

I've traced it down to this location in the upload.php file:

```
...
//start of the file upload, first chunk
if ($currByte == 0) {
    $tempFile           = tempnam($this->tempPath, 'axupload');
    $this->tempFileName = basename($tempFile);
}

// some rare times (on very very fast connection), file_put_contents will be unable to write on the file,
// so we try until it writes for a max of 5 times
$try = 5;
while (file_put_contents($tempFile, $fileChunk, FILE_APPEND) === false && $try > 0) {
   usleep(50);
   $try--;
}

//if the above fails then user cannot write file due to permission or other problems
if (!$try) {
   $this->message(-1, 'Cannot write on file.');
}
...
```

I assumed this meant that `$tempFile` was not writable, so I added this bit:

```
...
//start of the file upload, first chunk
if ($currByte == 0) {
    $tempFile           = tempnam($this->tempPath, 'axupload');
    $this->tempFileName = basename($tempFile);
 }

 chmod($tempFile, 0755);
 ...
```

I tried it again and I still had a problem, so I changed the permissions of /tmp to 755, thinking maybe that was the case. Again, nothing.

I could try to just change the location of my /tmp directory and have a more writable environment, but if there's an easier solution I'd rather go with that.

Thank you.

Comment: have you checked increasing the values in php.ini settings like upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Yeah. I have both at 256M with -1 memory limit. My file is 80M. The chunking breaks like, 3% into it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all upload a small file in a directory and check whether it uploads successfully or not. If successful, than search for the `php.ini` setting file and check the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

update all the above settings to meet your requirement and after that restart the server and then try again.